# Как получить данные JSON в Yii2 из view?

Tags: php, ajax, json, yii2

Не могу заставить работать скрипт в Yii2 для получения json данных из базы данных.
есть файл /modules/maps/views/object/objectsjson.php (упростил.., вообще данные берутся из базы):

```
echo '{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна", "clusterCaption": "Еще одна метка", "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна", "clusterCaption": "Еще одна метка", "hintContent": "Текст подсказки"}}
        ]
}';
```

и есть яваскрипт который обращается к этому файлу (пример взят [отсюда](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager)):

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [сenter1,сenter2],
            zoom: 1,
      type: 'yandex#satellite'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            clusterize: true,
            gridSize: 32
        });
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://site.ru/basic/web/index.php?r=maps%2Fobject%2Fobjectsjson"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });

}
```

на выходе пусто.. но если этот файл положить в папку web и прописать

```
$.ajax({
        url: "objectsjson.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });
```

то всё работает!
В контроллере вот что?

```
public function actionObjectsjson()
{
    return $this->render('objectsjson');
}
```

Где ошибка? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в контроллере вот что:

Answer (score 1):

В `$json` ваш файл в json формате

```
    public function actionObjectsjson()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;   
    return $json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если через `rest`, тогда экшены по умолчанию отдают json заголовок

```
<?php
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController {
    ...
}
```

Если же по стандарту, для отрисовки `html` используйте `use yii\web\Controller;` чтобы потом решать где будет приходить другой ответ. Например в контроллере можно написать функцию (лучше конечно отдельный класс для этого создать), что-то типа этого:

```
public function Responce($res)
{
    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return $response->data = $res;
}
```

Теперь при создании экшена, который отдаёт json, можно вернуть данные функцией:

```
public function actionBlog($link = '')
{
    $comments = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE `status`=2 AND `url`="/blog/'.$link.'"';
    $res = Post::find()
        ->select('*, ('.$comments.') as number_of_comments' )
        ->with('author', 'comment')
        ->where(['link' => $link, 'type' => 'блог'])
        ->asArray()
        ->one();
    return self::Responce($res);
}
```

Теперь, по данному примеру вы можете получить пост по ссылке в виде json который вернёт один пост, количество комментариев и все комментарии с данными об авторе, а так же данные самих комментаторов. Три таблицы, один запрос, один выход в формате json :-)